# Rewrite a polynomial function in a power of (x-2).

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

I've been looking at my notes completely stumped trying to figure out how to approach this question, the question is as follows:

Write $f(x) = 3x^5 - 2x^4 + x^3 - 5x^2 - 7x + 11$ in the power of (x-2).

Comment: See [Ruffini's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Hint:

use Taylor series at $x=2$
$$f(x)=f(2)+{\frac {f'(2)}{1!}}(x-2)+{\frac {f''(2)}{2!}}(x-2)^{2}+{\frac {f'''(2)}{3!}}(x-2)^{3}+\cdots .$$

Comment: So using the series I would apply the terms with corresponding powers together? For some reason I've been pretty good at calc, but this taylor series is getting me.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x-2$.  Then we have a polynomial in $x=y+2$, $f(x)=3(y+2)^5−2(y+2)^4+(y+2)^3−5(y+2)^2−7(y+2)+11$.  Now expand everything out.  (Note, this may end up being more work than the hint of @E.H.E.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write $f(x+2) = 3(x+2)^5 - 2(x+2)^4 + (x+2)^3 - 5(x+2)^2 - 7(x+2)x + 11$. Expand the powers and collect the terms to get $f(x+2)=3 x^5 + a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + e$. Then $f(x)=3 (x-2)^5 + a (x-2)^4 + b (x-2)^3 + c (x-2)^2 + d (x-2) + e$.